# How to force the recreation of thumbnail in SolidWorks?

Tags: vba, thumbnails, solidworks

I have 5000 converted CAD files from an old system.

Usually SolidWorks creates thumbnails that can be seen in Windows Explorer as a preview.

The thumbnails are showing the part in miniature. This is caused by the conversion - the part is positioned outside the active screen area, and the thumbnail is created from that, thus showing a ridicules large area in the thumbnail.

Example
[image]

The manual resolution:

1. open the part in SolidWorks
2. Scale to fit to get the part in the viewing area at max size
3. rebuild the part
4. save the part (after saving, the correct thumbnail is directly visible in Explorer)
5. close the SolidWorks window

I created VBA code to do the same, it does all the above except the recreation of the thumbnail.

```vb
Sub main()
    Dim swApp As Object
    Dim swModelDoc As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
    Dim Part As Object
    Dim boolstatus As Boolean
    Dim longstatus As Long, longwarnings As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim Path As String

    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
    Set swModelDoc = swApp.ActiveDoc

    With swModelDoc
        Path = .GetPathName
        FileName = .GetTitle
        .ViewZoomtofit2
        .ForceRebuild3 True
        .GraphicsRedraw2
        .Save
    End With

    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swPart = Nothing
    Set Part = Nothing
    swApp.CloseDoc FileName
End Sub
```

As far as I can see this is done during the save operation.

How do I force the creation of the thumbnail during or before the save action?

Comment: Hi OP can you please [edit] your question using the toolbar edit buttons. Good luck!

Comment: It seems that SolidWorks supports [recording VBA macros](https://help.solidworks.com/2021/english/SolidWorks/sldworks/c_recording_playing_macros.htm). Do your manual steps while the macro recorder is running, and inspect the generated code for differences to what you tried. It's not unlikely that the crucial step you're missing gets recorded.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Tomalak,, I did do that as well it generates the code slightly different but the result is the same. if I run the recorded macro the thumbnail is not increased in size even though the zoomfit works , the force rebuild works and the save works. this is the reason I posted here because it has me puzzled right now

Answer (score 0):

Below is a part of a Macro i made while back, that ends by making a zoom-to-fit,
and saves the file to a new location; i know this is generating the correct thumbnails... the only real difference i see, is that i use SaveAs,
could you give that a try, and simply letting it overwrite the old file?

```
'Zoom to Fit
swModel.ViewZoomtofit2
  
'declare a new location for the file, and save it, using the original file-name.
Dim saveFile As Long
saveFile = swModel.SaveAs3(path & "Output\" & sFileName, 0, 0)


'Get title of the open file, and close it.
Dim partTitle As String
partTitle = swModel.GetTitle
swApp.CloseDoc partTitle
```

If you are still having problems; where are your files located?
if they are being handled in a PDM-Vault, it could very well be the environments that holds on to the old thumbnails.